# evince doesn't adapt window size to screen size

Tags: xorg, gnome, xfce, evince

I use my laptop with external screens whose resolution and position differ depending on whether I am at work or at home. Most Xorg applications cope with this quite well. Evince however does not, and frequently opens with a window size that exceeds by far the screen on which it displays.

I am not sure whether this is a specificity of evince or of all windows with what I think is a gnome "header bar" (which includes part of the GUI of application) rather than a traditional titlebar.

Note that I'm running XFCE 4.16.

My questions are:

- is this a bug, and if so, is it a gnome, xfce or evince bug?
- are there tweaks to make sure evince doesn't open in a larger-than-screen size?

[EDIT] Testing a few things empirically, it seems that `evince` keeps window location and size for each pdf file separately.

Following @meuh's comments, I tested `gsettings` queries and settings:

- It doesn't list a size in pixels, relevant ones are `fullscreen`, `window-ratio`, and `sizing-mode` options which has value `free`.
- Setting `fullscreen` to `true`, evince does open fullscreen (not maximised, real <kbd>F11</kbd> fullscreen) for pdf files which (seemingly) have never been opened with evince, but keeps last size and position for those which have.

So my updated question is whether it is possible to override this memory of position and size, globally or conditionally.

Comment: Evince has known a few bugs and fixes relating to its window size. It's probably a bug, to be reported to the developers.

Comment: Evince may just be saving the window size of a previous run and helpfully re-applying it on the next run. You can get at the gnome settings with `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.Evince.Default` and so on. I'm not a gnome user so don't know much more about this.

Comment: @meuh: I guess this is the case, but `gsettings` doesn't list any size in pixels. Updating answer since the behaviour seems to be more complicated than that.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this problem using devilspie2.
In my case, I created the following configuration file
~/.config/devilspie2/myconfig.lua:

```
if get_application_name() == "Document Viewer" then
    maximize();
end
```

Where "Document Viewer" is the name of the evince window on my system. This name may change depending on your system (start devilspie in debug mode to get the correct name).

After that, just configure devilspie2 to start with your session and evince should automatically work as you expect.

Devilspie2 tutorial:
https://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2017/205/Tutorial-Devilspie2

Comment: Thanks - I don't seem to have the problem anymore at present. I only use evince occasionally (mostly for printing, it's still better at it than okular, but for other aspects I prefer the latter) so not sure when this has changed or whether it's 100% solved.